# What does the phrase "by the time token" mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I saw the sentence "by the time token" in a physics textbook. The original sentence is:

> By the time token, if E < V(and V is constant), then Y is exponential.

In Cambridge Dictionary, "token" means "symbol", but obviously it doesn't suit the context here. Can anyone please explain what the phrase means?

Comment: Doesn't the book mention such a token earlier in the paragraph or chapter?

Comment: Difficult to say without more context. It's possible that what they meant to say was ***by the same token***, but just made a mistake and wrote ***by the time token*** instead.

Comment: Try checking the index at the back of the textbook, there's a pretty good chance it has one. If you're still struggling, I'll be more than happy to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go with Cookie Monster on this one and suggest it's a misprint.  The common expression is "by the same token", meaning "in the same way".

> If I leave my house at 5 in the morning, I can beat the traffic and get to work in half an hour.  **By the same token** if I leave work before 3, I can get home in the same amount of time.

It's possible that "time token" has a specific meaning in the textbook, which would have been earlier defined, but there isn't enough context in your example to be sure.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. A quick Internet search located this quotation in _Introduction to Quantum Mechanics_ by D.J. Griffiths at the top of page 316. http://www.pd.infn.it/~zwirner/WKB-1-2.pdf

Comment: @joiedevivre Yes, you are correct. I was reading Griffths's Introduction to QM and there's a misprint in my book. Thanks:)